# Svelte class based component example

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm trying to learn Svelte and TypeScript. I was wondering if there is any pattern to include or program svelte component using ES6 classes. Currently file contains all the script, html and data, css. I want to make them separate files. Please help me!

Comment: There's an [issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/65) to allow separation of input HTML, CSS and JS. The JS would still need to conform to the normal component structure, however — that's how the compiler is able to do its static analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a task runner to automate this. If you are using es6 classes I would recommend using `rollup` with `rollup-plugin-svelte` and `rollup-plugin-buble`.

I use Gulp to take the separate js, html and css files and concat them into a single file with the appropriate tags enclosing the script and styles. The combined file can be compiled then deleted.

**Structure**

To help keep the file files clean and easy to work with the HTML, CSS and JavaScript can be seperate.

src/hello/hello.css

```
.message {
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

src/hello/hello.html

```
<div class="message">{{message}}</div>
```

src/hello/hello.js

```
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: 'Hello, world!'
    }
  }
}
```

**Combine**

Svelte requires that components be just a single html file, so the three separate files need to be combined into a single file. Since this file is HTML, the JavaScript must be wrapped in  tags and the CSS must be wrapped in  tags.

src/hello/hello.temp.html

```
<style>
.message {
  font-size: 10pt;
}
</style>

<div class="message">{{message}}</div>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: 'Hello, world!'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Compile**

The temp file can be compiled using svelte or rollup with the svelte plugin then deleted.

[Edit]
Here is a gist with a gulp file showing how this works.
[Link here](https://gist.github.com/ZacBrownBand/3be50d8c36c234960c73e6bdc3a44c6c)

[Edit 2]
**There is a Yeoman generator to set this all up for you, here is a link to the npm package.** 
[generator-svelte-workbench](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-svelte-workbench)

Comment: Hi @Zac, yeah I think above approach works pretty well. I didn't realize until  now, we can combine using gulp different files while still be able to use the new syntax and converting to above format before passing to svelte plugin. Is it also possible to share you `gulpfile.js` gulp config ? or `repository` on github ? Would be nice to learn more about it!

Comment: I would be happy to, I'll post it tomorrow. I ended up needed a few gulp plugins to get it to work well.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks @Zac. Also, it would be cool, once you upload the repo , better to add the link in the answer and I'll mark as accepted +1

Comment: @PiyushChauhan Just added the link to a gist. Its here: https://gist.github.com/ZacBrownBand/3be50d8c36c234960c73e6bdc3a44c6c
Let me know if you have any issues, I tried to remove some of the clutter and hope I did not break anything.

Comment: Thanks @Zac, appreciated :)